# RavenDB throwing datetime error when used with OData having a date filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, ravendb

I am working on a .Net project where I am using Asp.Net Web Api and OData to query an Embedded Raven database. I have a separate repository project where the RavenDB stuff is placed and I am accessing this repository in my Web Api Project.

Below is how the RavenDB repository is set up with dummy data :

```
    public class EmployeeRepository
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IDocumentStore> Store = new Lazy<IDocumentStore>(CreateInstance);

        public static IDocumentStore DocumentStore
        {
            get { return Store.Value; }
        }

        private static IDocumentStore CreateInstance()
        {
            var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
            {
                DataDirectory = "Data",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = false,
                DefaultDatabase = "EmployeeDocumentDB"
            }.Initialize();

            using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                //TODO: Generates test data and can be deleted.
                PopulateEmployeesIfStoreIsEmpty(session);
            }

            return documentStore;
        }

        private static void PopulateEmployeesIfStoreIsEmpty(IDocumentSession session)
        {
            if (!session.Query<Employee>().Any())
            {
                var document1 = new Employee
                {
                    Id=1,
                    JoiningDate = new DateTime(2015, 01, 15),
                    BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01)
                };

                var document2 = new Employee
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    JoiningDate = new DateTime(2015, 02, 15),
                    BirthDate = new DateTime(1985, 01, 01)
                };


                session.Store(document1);
                session.Store(document2);

                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.Query<Employee>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how the Employee class looks like :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how the ApiController looks like :

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("employee/list")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEmployees(ODataQueryOptions<Employee> options)
    {
        try
        {
            EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
            var queryable = options.ApplyTo(employeeRepository.GetEmployees(), new ODataQuerySettings
            {
                EnableConstantParameterization = false,
                HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.False
            });

            var employees = RetriveEmployeeListFromQueryable(queryable);

            return Ok(employees);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
        }
    }

    private List<Employee> RetriveEmployeeListFromQueryable(IQueryable queryable)
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>();
        var enumerator = queryable.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var employee = enumerator.Current as Employee;
            employees.Add(employee);
        }
        return employees;
    }
}
```

I am using OData to Consume above code using a ApiController and when I fire below query in the web browser

```
http://localhost/employee/list?$filter=BirthDate eq 1985-01-01
```

I get an error stating :

> "Could not understand how to translate 'IIF((($it.JoiningDate.Kind == Utc) OrElse ($it.JoiningDate.Kind == Local)), new DateTimeOffset($it.JoiningDate.ToUniversalTime()).ToOffset(-06:00:00), new DateTimeOffset($it.JoiningDate, (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada).GetUtcOffset($it.JoiningDate)).ToUniversalTime().ToOffset(-06:00:00))' to a RavenDB query.\ \ Are you trying to do computation during the query?\ \ RavenDB doesn't allow computation during the query, computation is only allowed during index. Consider moving the operation to an index."

Comment: It would appear that OData is trying to do some stuff that Raven doesn't like with your `JoiningDate` property, but the query you show doesn't even have that.  Are you sure that's the full OData query?  Or perhaps you are manipulating it further in your controller?  Please show that part of your controller.  (The part that makes the call to `GetEmployees`).

Comment: Hi Matt, I have update the question with details you requested, please let me know in case if you need any additional information, thank in advance.

Comment: It's not a Raven issue, but rather it's related to OData v4 deprecating `DateTime` support, favoring `DateTimeOffset`.  This turned out to be an unpopular decision, and is on the agenda for reversing in OData v5.  I'll see if I can find a workaround for Raven and post an answer in the next day or two.

Comment: BTW - your `RetriveEmployeeListFromQueryable` is unnecessary.  Just cast - `var queryable = (IQueryable<Employee>) options.ApplyTo(...`  Then you can call `ToList()` on it.

Comment: That will be great! Thanks Matt.

Comment: The quickest way would probably be to define your types as `DateTimeOffset` - which would be good for `JoiningDate`, but is a bit noise for `BirthDate`.

Comment: Thank you Matt! Your solution worked flawlessly.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I'd still like to leave this open for now.  I'll put a more detailed response in explaining things later.  Thanks.

Comment: I am having another interesting issue and I am not able to figure out if its Asp.Net WebAPI doing it wrong or RavenDB.
When I preform a query 
http://localhost/employee/list?$filter=BirthDate ge 1985-01-01
I do not get records with employees with `BarthDate = 1985-01-01`, the query always returns the `GreaterThan` result and not the `EqualTo`result

Comment: It's likely that the offset portion of the `DateTimeOffset` type is not matched between what is stored and what is queried.  Like I said, it's a bit of noise for a birth date.  It might need to be adjusted to UTC (+00:00).   You might try NodaTime's `LocalDate` type, which will just store `YYYY-MM-DD` in to Raven [when using these extensions](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-NodaTime).  Though I'm not sure if it will work with odata or not (haven't tried).